# Retrieve tags from user profile in IBM Connections using Social Business Toolkit does not give tags

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

Hi we want to add tags to a userprofile programmatically.
We are using the **Social Business Toolkit** for this purpose.
More specifically we use the ProfileService, first we need to get the current tags and this always gives **0** results.

```
String userEmail = "ABC@XYZ.com";

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            EntityList<Tag> tags = app.profileService.getTags(userEmail, params);
```

or

```
EntityList<Tag> tags = app.profileService.getTags("427ffbb1-ab50-4e82-97b2-46bf5584e799");
```

both give no tags (tags.size == 0) when we try to print them

```
if (tags.size() <= 0) {
                System.out.println("No tags to be displayed");
            }
            for (Tag tag : tags) {
                System.out.println("Tag : " + tag.getTerm());
                System.out.println("Tag Frequency:  " + tag.getFrequency());
                System.out.println("Tag Visibility : "
                        + tag.isVisible());
                System.out.println("");
            }
```

I have tried to test this with Connections Cloud and Greenhouse , but for those platforms I get authorization errors.
I tried this both with a 4.5 and 5.0 Connections environment, both giving the same result.
However when I use the URL

```
profiles/atom/profileTags.do?targetEmail=ABC%40YYZ.com
```

I do get (XML) results.

We are using version 1.1.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both environments, you need to use the key to access a user's tags. 
https://apps.na.collabserv.com/profiles/atom/profileTags.do?targetKey=fb4435f4-f67d-4f4e-b905-669a31445d0f

You can get the key from the service document. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/appdevwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=API+Reference#action=openDocument&res_title=Retrieving_the_Profiles_service_document_ic50&content=apicontent

Those two environments do not use targetEmail.

Thanks

Paul

Comment: Thanks @paul-bastide , good to know, but what I meant is:
The SBT does not return any tags from a user profile, where I can see clearly in the ATOM xml that there are tags for this profile. Even when we have an "on prem" installation

Comment: yes, that is a defect in the current code. most likely the ProfileXPath needs to be updated -  tagEntry("/app:categories/a:category"), or the code to instantiate a Tag needs to be updated.  either way it's a defect. please open a  github issue